# Can a producer in another jar be used for bean injection?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

I have a utility jar that has a logger producer, and I am working on another project using Arquillian for testing. In the project, I have a class with `@Inject Logger logger`. When I run tests with Arquillian, I got an error saying that `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point`. I have successfully used producer from current project to produce a logger bean before, but this is the first time I have tried to use a producer from another jar (or a dependency). So, I am wondering if producers have to be in the same project or they can be in other jars. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is the jar being added to the Arquillian `Archive`?

Comment: @rubenlop88: I see your question. I have actually solved my problem. What you can do is just add the package containing the producer or the producer class from another jar into the Arquillian archive by using the normal method such as `addClasses` and `addPackages`. This will enable the injection for the producer.

Comment: This type of error generally occurs when you forget to add certain classes to the `Archive`, thats why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think see the issue-- This is not wrong with Arquillian.

**Explicit jar** contain the beans.xml file, that can be an empty, either it contain no version number, or contain the version number 1.1 with the bean-discovery-mode attribute set to all. such as:

For JavaEE7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>
```

> CDI will not manage and inject those beans which are annotated with
>   @Voted

Another one is **implicit bean archive**,that contains some beans annotated with a scope type, contains no beans.xml files or contains a beans.xml file with the bean-discovery-mode attribute set to annotated.

> CDI can only manage and inject beans annotated with a scope type in an
>   implicit archive.

Refer Java Tutorial

[Packaging CDI Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv001.htm#CACDCFDE)

[Weld-Doc](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#4)